# Avoid accidental overwrite between different developers upon checkin or merge

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Different developers check in the code touching the same file or different branches could be getting merged. I am new to TFS from the admin side but I do know how to do basic check-in of the code. How can I avoid the code collision from admin side? We are using Microsoft Team foundation server as version control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Version control systems are made to allow different users to edit the same files and so that when merging, it provides a reasonable experience upon merge. The ability to check out the same file by multiple developers is one of the things that allows teams to become highly productive. When multiple versions of the same product are being developed or maintained, it's impossible to prevent conflicts altogether.

There is a lot of additional guidance available [through the ALM RAngers' guides](https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/). I highly recommend you and your developers read this.

### Note:

Visual Studio 2013 offers a much better merge experience than older versions. 3rd party tools like [Semantic Merge](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2528ed09-0518-4da5-a988-bdc2eacfcc27) further improve the experience by parsing the code being merged and applying some additional intelligent logic to prevent conflicts.

For certain notoriously hard to merge files, like SSIS packages, there are additional specialist tools such as [BIDS Helper Smart Diff](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/).

*Some things you can do:*

### Make sure developers communicate

Teams that do a daily scrum (stand-up meeting) or have the ability to use Team Rooms in TFS can signal intent and keep others up to date on what they're doing pro-actively. Making sure that there is a dedicated communication channel available and that the users have the [Team Rooms extension installed](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c1bf5e4f-5436-465d-87da-09b2f15ff061) in case they're not co-located. Communication prevents many of these type of issues and is the best solution once such a merge issue occurs.

### Have developers perform a get-latest and check-in frequently

While there is no server setting for this, having your developers trained on branching, merging and general source control patterns can help a lot. If a user regularly checks for incoming changes (get latest) and checks in as soon as he is relatively confident about his code (say after the first test passes when using TDD), then chances of conflicts is substantially lower.

### The Incoming Changes Lens

[Codelens has been updated with a new Lens as one of the updates that was released after RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/03/03/new-codelens-indicator-incoming-changes.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0). The lens requires both the Client and the Server to be upgraded to at least Update 2 and at least Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 2. It's recommended that when you start applying the Updates, you always stay current, thus I'd recommend you install Update 4.

While Code Lens is an Ultimate feature, it will be moved into Professional with the release of Visual Studio 2015.

### Use Exclusive Checkout

If users use the [Checkout and lock option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181419.aspx) to check out a file, they can signal other users that the file is undergoing major changes. This feature requires that all users have their workspace type set to "Server Workspace". Local workspaces, given their disconnected nature, ignore the Lock flag. Though individual users can always override their workspace type, it is possible to set the [default workspace type at the collection level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/05/set-local-workspaces-as-default-when-upgrading-to-tfs-2012.aspx).

### Disable Merging and Multiple checkout for individual file types

A better solution is to mark file types that are hard to merge, the old style SSIS packages with lots of XML and GUIDs are agood candidate here. [Open the Source Control settings and add the extensions of "bad files".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252452%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) This setting applies partially in Visual Studio regardless of the workspace setting (Visual Studio will only offer <kbd>Take Local</kbd> or <kbd>Take Server</kbd> and will not offer to merge.

### Disable Multiple Checkout

It is possible to set the Project's Source Control option [not allow "Multiple Checkouts"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), this will automatically acquire a Lock when a file is checked out. It's not recommended to turn this feature on, as it introduces a lot of frustrating things while working in Visual Studio (most importantly when adding any file, one has to acquire a lock on the project file). As with Exclusive Checkout, this requires all users to use Server Workspaces.

As this feature will prevent any file from being checked out by multiple people, it's often trying to apply way to much force to solve this issue. Only in case your developers mess up on a high frequency, you may enable this feature temporarily while they receive training.