# Make developers checkout (get latest changes) before commit

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, policy, tfvc

Is there an option in TFS to make developers get latest changes before they commit?

I have a few developers who are reluctant to update (and check that their changes actually work with the current version), and just commit. Very often breaking the build this way.

We have a CI build every 15 minutes, but this is also about developers using other developer's changes early.

Note: We are considering switching to git just over this issue.

Comment: You can probably make a custom checkin policy to enforce this. Check the local workspace version against the server version of the same workspace. This policy should get you started: https://github.com/jessehouwing/tfstools

Comment: Well, we are mostly using Java - Eclipse with TEE plugin. That link is C# solution for VS.

Comment: You can build a Checkin policy in java as well.I suspect you'll need to build both C# and Java for configurability. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/800/develop-custom-checkin-policy-tfs-sdk-java

Comment: If a build is running every 15 minutes, it's not a CI build. A CI build runs on every commit.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30265509/736079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure your build to be a true CI build, though it will not prevent people from checking in before getting latest. It should detect who broke which build. Some people will even configure a Gated build to not even check in without a passing build. I personally dislike this, as it slows down integration, often considerably.

To catch the case you want to catch, you could implement a Custom Checkin Policy, register it with TFS and install it to all the Visual Studio and Team Explorer Everywhere installations in your organisation. Creating a policy is pretty straightforward:

- C#: https://github.com/jessehouwing/tfstools
- Java: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/800/develop-custom-checkin-policy-tfs-sdk-java

And you'll have to build both, since the configuration of checkin policies happens through Visual Studio and requires the C# implementation.
BAsically you'd query the local workspace version and compare that against latest workspace version on the server. Optionally scoped to only the files changed. Your developer should then get-latest, rebuild, rerun all unit tests and try to check in again. This may cause another collision.

I've written more guidance on this topic in a very similar previous question. I suspect your problem is worse than a simple check in the tools, it's a people thing where people may not really care about what others are doing and where they're not communicating enough to pre-empt these kinds of conflicts.

See also: [Avoid accidental overwrite between different developers upon checkin or merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30265509/736079)

Comment: Well, I hoped to find some TFS configuration, but for the only way is to do some plugin.

Comment: I understand you wish. But unfortunately, there is no such feature built in.

Answer (score 1):

This could depend on a few things but most relevant could be the workspace setup (local or server). For example, the **server workspace** provides you the option to enforce the get latest.

When you are using  server workspace, you can configure Team Foundation version control to get the latest version of a file when you check it out. When this option is enabled, the check-out behavior is like *Visual SourceSafe*.  More details please refer this link: [Enable Team Foundation Version Control to Get the Latest Files on Check-Out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385989(v=vs.100).aspx)

If you have to work with local workpsace, then just as *jessehouwing* suggested, the best way is using **custom checkin policy**. About how to do it, please refer this blog: [Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)

Comment: but it is possible to commit without checking-out first.

Comment: @PaulVerest Well, if so no this build-in option. Moreover, *Daniel* is right. CI build is if you want the build to run whenever someone checks in code. Without the 15 minutes buffer, your developers should get the breaking build info once commit in source control. If  one personal often encountered such a problem, he will  remember get latest  then. It's also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

We are generally using Gated builds, so that changes are only checked-in if it compiles, FxCop is happy and the unit test are green. We have tried for many years with CI triggered test and analysis, but the learnings have been that **trust is good, but gates are better**.

This does however require that the build and validation time is fairly short, so that integration is not slowed down.